# decode hex encoded cbor string as a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, hex, decode, cbor

I have this hex encoded cbor string that I need decoded as a string: 821a0485c1e3ae581c368bedeac13b8f1fbc30cdaadb987635ff95e88960b1ea216e3f96faa14f74656e7461696c656761637931323201581c3dc002874772549f7758066ae025b92a4dab66c57d187dd78821b673a34a6c746c6d6b7973363535014a6c746c6d6b7973383333014b6c746c6d6b79733238393901581c482fb00dc32186a4c587dca2df3c7cf2bc455332ab581d51967306e1a1444d4f4149190743581c49da502b625d310ad3a742c1e747c0027e83426f8717180b21c871b1a14959524941433136373401581c4b92de6b0398970dcafe4aee5329e591819ca11aa3dc163a981c7f99a54f4d654d654f66546865446179363534014f4d654d654f6654686544617937343001504d654d654f665468654461793132343001504d654d654f665468654461793133373801504d654d654f665468654461793234343901581c561696ab9e70db98f8ff5c12f0fdbd837bd1b95d84c748b04ede8fbaa14441504f43190226581c5993061274861159508aef767fc0ccd8b8a9b836171a989ad543fa1fa74f44446f53546573744d696e74373432015044446f53546573744d696e7431323132015044446f53546573744d696e7431333238015044446f53546573744d696e7432333130015044446f53546573744d696e7432393239015044446f53546573744d696e7433303037015044446f53546573744d696e743330313701581c5cf33cfea1b37c289060f55fa09c1fb3b9cb6972e40d9ed2f94a5adaa14f484d5072696f4d6f6e73746572313901581c9b542bc33521163a7ff3a05d1df1bcc0c0ec6a0638337e4b2870f6eaa153496e74726f76657274736d636172643034303201581caaf1f848b36940b0703f43f8d406b815132efe64fccb34bc30f993a0a14f466c7566667957686974656c69737401581cc76975c66380ad2bcdf6b465b3b0df34bdd76112046979b9a834364fa1534f4e434841494e20534b554c4c20233038353301581cd79181749db228d10c98501a7e1728585780bcf133b7b3df953a9017a24e496e74726f766572747332313135014e496e74726f76657274733436383901581cdd589bbcfa48c9a133a22e205da33a5d07ef79dac1f8d5d8067b1004a158187768657265734472696c6c646f54686557616c646f39353301581cf8ed2f8e4fdc992644710e45be7fdc4a556b7517ee2956414b5c2b25a14d434e4654536c6162733032373601

I found this website: https://cbor.me/ which are able to decode it as a string as seen in the picture
[image]

And I have been trying to figure out how it works so I could recreate it in my own code, but have been unsuccessful.

I have tried this, which gives me a string like I wanted but it doesn't decode the words as seen in the picture:

```
buf = new Uint8Array(itxt.match(/.{1,2}/g).map(byte => parseInt(byte, 16)))

data = await cbor.diagnose(buf)
console.log(data)
```

[image]

So I have come here to ask if any of you might know the code to do it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log(data.replace(/h'(.*?)'/g, function(m, p) {
  var s = Buffer.from(p, "hex").toString();
  if (/\P{L}/u.test(s)) return m;
  else return `'${s}'`;
}));
```

replaces the hex strings with UTF-8 strings, unless the UTF-8 string would contain a non-letter ([regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) `\P{L}`).

An alternative to using the `Buffer` class is the code you already gave in your question:

```js
var s = p.match(/.{1,2}/g)
  .map(byte => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(byte, 16))).join("");
```

Comment: hey, i get referenceError Buffer is not defined. i think i get this because Buffer is only used in node.js, but i don't use node. Do you have an alternative?

Comment: See my augmented answer.

Comment: I changed \P{L} to \p{S} in the regular expression and the code now works. thank you so much :)